# Send signed transaction hash to the network

Tags: transactions, signature, raw-transaction, hash, parity-signer

The [Parity native signing app](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer) takes the hash of a transaction and signs this has with a private key, derived from a seed phrase. Below is the corresponding code from [signer.js](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer/blob/master/src/actions/signer.js#L43):

```
let account = getState().accounts.selected
let hash = getState().signer.hashToSign
let seed = await decryptData(account.encryptedSeed, pin)
let signature = await brainWalletSign(seed, hash)
```

The signature is then displayed as a QR code.

Can this signature be used to send the transaction to the network? If yes how would this be done in code?

Note: the signature is created from the hash of the transaction, not the transaction, and so does not contain the transaction details. Can the signature and the transaction data be combined somehow?